# JS Remove multi-dimensional data property using array of properties

Tags: javascript

Basically I have got an object, which will be multi-dimensional and the properties could be named anything and it could have many dimensions.

At some point I will need to append/splice a property within this object, from code which won't know it's position.

So, an example object:

```
let obj = {
    response: {
        locations: {
            data: [
                0: Object,
                1: Object,
                2: Object,
            ]
        }
    },
    endpoint: null
}
```

I need to splice out `data.locations.data[1]`, the only information I have is the below array and the index. Obviously I will know the first property will be `response`.

```
['locations','data']

index: 1
```

---

**Edit:**

My mistake, the `data` property has an array value not an object!

Comment: if obj.response.locations.data  is an object you have to use delete obj.response.locations.data.1 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce()` and pass in `obj.response` as the start value to get at the nested parent which based on the array shown would be `obj.response.locations.data`.

Then `splice()` the indexed item in that parent or do whatever other modifications are needed

```js
const arr = ['locations','data'],
index= 1,
 obj = {
    response: {
        locations: {
            data: [{id:1},{id:2}, {id:3}]
        }
    },
    endpoint: null
}

const targetArr = arr.reduce((a,c)=> (a[c]), obj.response);
targetArr.splice(index,1);

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Hey that is close, but I should of mentioned the keys within `data` where not manually set, this is an array not an object. My mistake!

Comment: @MartynBall So in your case use the splice method :
obj.response.locations.data.splice(index,1);
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Figured it out, just change **delete** for `targetObj.splice(data.index, 1);`. And read the post @Nico